# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when want data for web stock

Tags: python-3.x, macos, frameworks, urllib, http-error

```
import re
import urllib.request
url='https://www.google.com/search?
tbm=fin&ei=ULxUWpvZJoKE8wWWzLDgBw&q='
n=input('Enter your stock name:')
url=url+n
m=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data=m.decode('utf-8')
print(data)
```

Actually i just wanted the data to be printed so that i could calculate the web stock of every site but this code gave an error:

OUTPUT:

```
Enter your stock name:GOOG
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Documents/Web Stock(revise).py", line 6, in <module>
    m=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Please help me to fix it!

Comment: Why `import re`? You never use. You also don't need to call `str` on `input()`; it already returns a `str` type. What does your full `url` variable look like before the call to `urlopen()`? Have you checked to make sure its valid?

Comment: @pstatix import re will be used further in code for searching name of stock. And yes the url is correct,you can check it by adding GOOG/FB after it.

Comment: Have you checked how `urllib.request` handles _https_?

Comment: No. Can you tell me how to check it? Or just tell me the mistake in my code.